# Android login is not working getting filenotfount exception

Tags: android

I developed one app and published on playstore also.

Till yestarday the CheckLogin Servlet is working means Login is working file but

from todays mornning it is not working

I am getting following exception

```
02-27 14:43:23.462 32275-6622/com.dhruva.eprintpost W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: path of URL
 02-27 14:43:23.463 32275-6622/com.dhruva.eprintpost W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
 02-27 14:43:23.463 32275-6622/com.dhruva.eprintpost W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
02-27 14:43:23.463 32275-6622/com.dhruva.eprintpost W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
 02-27 14:43:23.463 32275-6622/com.dhruva.eprintpost W/System.err:     at  com.dhruva.eprintpost.login.LoginActivity$10.run(LoginActivity.java:513)
 02-27 14:43:23.463 32275-6622/com.dhruva.eprintpost W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

and my Login sending request is as follows

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {

                                try {

                                    URL url = new URL(SessionManager.getAmateurPath() + "LoginCheck");
                                    Log.v("Urllll",""+url);
                                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                                    ComStr = "&usrnm=" + email + "&pwd=" + pwd;
                                    str = ComStr.getBytes();

                                    Log.d("inputString", email);
                                    Log.d("inputString", pwd);

                                    connection.setDoOutput(true);

                                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content=length", String.valueOf(str.length));
                                    os = connection.getOutputStream();
                                    os.write(str);
                                    os.flush();


                                    final String status;
                                    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                                    status = in.readLine();
                                    Log.d("Status", status);

                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            handleStatus(status, in);
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                                catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
```

Comment: check with your sever.

Comment: Checket but it is not working.

Comment: File is there at server.I hit that url from browser with respective parameter it working in chrome

Comment: What should i do now

Comment: Check your URL. IF possible give the output of Log.v("Urllll",""+url);

Answer (score 0):

**use this asynctask**

```
 private class SendGcmToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity_Register_Login.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        dialog.show();
        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            Log.e("***************registration_id", regid);
            regid = registerInBackground();

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url_for_getdata = Util.register_url;
        BufferedReader reader;


        String url_data = Util.register_url + "?username=" + editText_user_name.getText().toString() + "&password=" + editText_password.getText().toString() + "&vehId=" + edit_text_vehicle_no.getText().toString() + "&regId=" + regid;
        url_data = url_data.replace("\n", "%20");
        url_data = url_data.replace(" ", "%20");
        url_data = url_data.replace("'", "%20");
        System.out.println("url: " + url_data);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_data);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conection.setDoOutput(true);


            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line + "");

            }
            content = result.toString();
            System.out.println(content);
            getcontent_for_validate = content;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        JSONObject jsonobj;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        if (result != null) {
            if (result.equals("failure")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Check your Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();

            } else {//ths is getting data for vehicl_list_unread_count code, client id,restapi_key
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: this inner of post" + getcontent_for_validate);
                    jsonobj = new JSONObject(getcontent_for_validate);
                    System.out.println("this is get content" + jsonobj.toString());


                    JSONArray array = jsonobj.getJSONArray("Staff_Details");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        Clint_id = editText_user_name.getText().toString();
                        Api_key = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("api_key");
                        COMPANY_LOGO = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("company_logo");
                        Password = editText_password.getText().toString();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Database_for_user_details db = new Database_for_user_details(Activity_Register_Login.this);
                db.createEntry_for_clint_details(Clint_id, Password, Api_key, "login", edit_text_vehicle_no.getText().toString(), COMPANY_LOGO);

                db.createEntry_for_TRIP_STATUS();


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged-in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                System.out.println("get data" + "    " + Clint_id + "    " + Api_key);
                startActivity(new Intent(Activity_Register_Login.this, Activity_dashboard.class));
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();


            }


        } else {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Check net connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

**i hope this will help you**

Comment: this may not the answer while the problem belongs to server not code.

Comment: ya i understand. but he is not clear. tats y i answered another way in android.

Comment: Please give me the solution.My app on playstore is not working because of login

Comment: @unknownapk check your server-side code. This may not problem of Android code.

Comment: But when i hit that url from chrome browser it work fine.

Comment: FileNotFoundException: https://eprintpost.com/AndroidServlets1/LoginCheck

Comment: this excepthion only call 404 error thet means file not in your server

Comment: from the above link i got correct response in browser but not in android

Comment: use json parsing with my above code thet will help you